# How to change the face of a long line without affecting other font-lock customizations in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, customization, emacs-faces

I have some code that I borrowed from a long while ago that sets a long-line face when the line is too long:

```
 (add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook
           (function
            (lambda ()
              (setq font-lock-keywords
                    (append font-lock-keywords
                            '( ("^.\\{133,\\}$" (0 'my-long-line-face t))
                              )
                            )
                    )
              )
            ))
```

(I know about font-lock-add-keywords now, BTW; like I said, this is kind of old.)

The problem is that this changes the face of the entire line. So if I indicate that long-line-face is bold, I lose all the contextual customization of the line, and it appears in the default face, but bold.

How would I get it to keep the contextual colouring but make everything bold?

Comment: I used to do this, but I like the fill-column-indicator library better now. http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FillColumnIndicator

Comment: See the `See also` on the page Michael H. mentioned, for several other ways to highlight or otherwise indicate long lines.

Comment: I actually checked emacswiki first, but I didn't like any of the solutions there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the fontification with the `t` in your font-lock spec.  Try changing the `(0 'my-long-line-face t)` to either `(0 'my-long-line-face prepend)` or `(0 'my-long-line-face append)`.

Comment: Correct, with one minor correction. It needs to be either (0 'my-long-line-face prepend) or (0 'my-long-line-face append). But now it works like a charm; I didn't know about append and prepend. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this modification to your code:

```
(add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook
       (function
    (lambda ()
      (setq font-lock-keywords
        (append font-lock-keywords
            '( ("^.\\{133\\}\\(.*\\)$" (1 'my-long-line-face t))
              )
            )
        )
      )
    ))
```

The key being that you want the regexp to have a sub expression that follows the 133 characters that aren't too long, and then apply `my-long-line-face` to that following sub expression - as indicated by the 1 (instead of the 0 that you had).  See the info page for [Search-based Fontification](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html) for more details.

Comment: Definitely works as advertised, but I wanted something more like the answer scottfrazer gave. Thanks!